# Spam keyword detection?

Tags: discussion, spam

Shouldn't SO have some kind of spam or trolling keyword detection to prevent these kind of posts?

> [image]

Comment: Aside: the post and that user's account are both gone.

Comment: rude and abusive post/person, and incorrect grammar, NICE!

Comment: Why shouldn't gay people care for themselves? I'm confused.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Fortunately, we do!

[SmokeDetector](https://charcoal-se.org/#whats-smokey) is an open source project behind the [Charcoal organization](http://charcoal-se.org/). It's sole purpose is to detect spam, rude and abusive posts. These posts are reported to a variety of chat rooms<sup>1</sup> where volunteers analyze the contents and flag if necessary. Generally, these posts are deleted **within seconds**.

Smokey is learning on a daily basis as these volunteers constantly add new regex rules to catch these offensive posts. There are almost [90,000 true positives](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?feedback_filter=tp) caught by the project to date. Smokey watches over the entire Stack Exchange network in real time, giving reviewers the opportunity to remove this content before people even have the chance to see it.

If you want to get involved, feel free to ping an [admin](https://charcoal-se.org/people#admins) in [CHQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq)!

---

<sup>1. [CHQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq), [SOBotics](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics), [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)</sup>

Comment: Worth noting that SO specific posts are reported in SOCVR and SOBotics.